# AngularJs stop $interval for specific controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, setinterval

I was used $interval to run certain function in first controller. After redirect to second controller, still $interval registered function (implemented in first controller) was running. I want to stop $interval services without using destroy function.

Answer (score 5):

> [**Note:**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed
>   when you are finished with them. In particular they are not
>   automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's
>   element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and
>   make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment. See
>   the example below for more details on how and when to do this.

You could use the `cancel` method to clean `$interval` object. You should cancel out the `interval` while leaving the controller.

For that you need to add `eventListener` over `$scope`'s `$destroy` event, you could do cleaning stuff (eg. canceling interval object, canceling timeout object).

**Code**

```
var myInterval = $interval(function(){
   //your interval code
}, 1000)

//register this listener inside your controller where the interval belongs.
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $interval.cancel(myInterval)
});
```

[**Sample Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qLxmiaVNUy0dx5hKUmck?p=preview)

Comment: Where I want to use ClearInterval? is it in Second controller or first controller?

Comment: in this case, you should use above code in same controller

Answer (score 2):

Add the interval variable in rootScope. And cancel it in the second controller whenever it gets opened as shown below.

**First Controller**

```
$rootScope.stopInterval = $interval(function(){
   //code goes here
}, 1000);
```

**Second Controller**

```
$interval.cancel($rootScope.stopInterval);
```

> Note: Only flaw in this case is you need to stop it in all the controllers you use after first controller, but a reliable one.

Comment: using $rootScope for this is bad codestyle. Angular-way is to use custom service instead.